# How do I add a confirmation dialog to an android wear action?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I currently have an Android Wear action that is very destructive.  How could I add a confirmation dialog to that action before executing it.

For example, I have an action "Finish Workout" on the wear...once a user finishes their workout, they can't resume it.  I want to ask them 'Are you sure you want to finish your workout?'

how could i do this?

Comment: Not familiar with android wear, but I assume it's similar.
You can override onBackPressed in your main activity and construct an AlertDialog. You can give that Yes and No labelled keys and text.

Comment: And AndroidWear action is something, and there is no onBackPressed for Wear actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DelayedConfirmationView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/DelayedConfirmationView.html) that is designed to address this, see this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/confirm.html). It will give your users a chance to stop/cancel the operation if they decide to.